# How to start task in virtual sequence from testcase?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'd like to execute a virtual sequence's task as below:

```
class MYTest extends uvm_test;                                                                      
  
  my_base_ahb_vseq_c my_base_ahb_vseq;                                                              
  
  `uvm_component_utils_begin(MYTest)                                                                
    `uvm_component_utils_end                                                                        
  
  function new(string name = "MYTest",uvm_component parent);                                        
    super.new(name,parent);                                                                         
  endfunction : new                                                                                 
  
  virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);                                               
    super.build_phase(phase); 
    my_base_ahb_vseq = my_base_ahb_vseq_c::type_id::create("my_base_ahb_vseq", this);                  
  endfunction : build_phase
  

  virtual function void end_of_elaboration_phase(uvm_phase phase);
        uvm_root uvm_top = uvm_root::get();
        super.end_of_elaboration_phase(phase);
        `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("MYTest!!! \n %0s", uvm_top.sprint()), UVM_LOW)
  endfunction

   task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);                                                                               
        phase.raise_objection(this);
        `uvm_info(get_type_name(), "My AHB Test Start!!", UVM_LOW)                                                        
        my_base_ahb_vseq.do_write(8'h12, 8'h34);                                                     
        phase.drop_objection(this);                                                                                   
    endtask
```

I implemented the virtual sequence as below:

```
class my_base_ahb_vseq_c extends AhbUvmUserVirtualSeq;

    myAhbTransaction trans;
    
    `uvm_object_utils_begin(my_base_ahb_vseq_c)
      `uvm_field_object(trans, UVM_ALL_ON)
    `uvm_object_utils_end
    
    function new(string name="my_base_ahb_vseq_c");
        super.new(name);
    endfunction // new

 endclass
```

When I execute `MYTest`, I got the error message below:

```
xmsim: *E,TRNULLID: NULL pointer dereference.
          File: VirtualSeqLib.sv, line = 258, pos = 13
         Scope: pstest.my_base_ahb_vseq_c@3148_1.do_write
          Time: 0 FS + 33
Verilog Stack Trace:
0: task pstest.my_base_ahb_vseq_c@3148_1.do_write at ../VirtualSeqLib.sv:258
1: task pstest.MYTest@3049_1.run_phase at ../UserTest.sv:37
```

How do I execute the virtual sequence's task in the test class correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the error message means that you declared an object but you did not construct the object before you tried to use it.  A declared object defaults to the value `null`.  You would construct an object using the `new` or `create` functions.

I assume line 258 is the following:

```
    `uvm_do_on_with(trans, p_sequencer.masterSeqr1, {
```

The message is not specific enough to determine which pointer is `null`: `trans` or `p_sequencer.masterSeqr1`.  If we assume `trans` is `null`, you could try to construct it somewhere, such as in the constructor for the `my_base_ahb_vseq_c` class:

```
function new(string name="my_base_ahb_vseq_c");
    super.new(name);
    trans = new();
endfunction // new
```

Otherwise, the error likely is due to `p_sequencer.masterSeqr1`.  In that case, you need to track down how you implemented the sequencer.  It might be in your `env` class.

---

Note that `32'addr` is a syntax error.  It is surprising that your compiler accepts it.  I don't think this is related to your reported error, but you should fix it.  For example, change:

```
            FirstAddress == 32'addr;
```

to:

```
            FirstAddress == addr;
```

---

I notice your [UVM sequence](https://www.chipverify.com/uvm/how-to-create-and-use-a-sequence) does not have a task named `body`.  It is conventional to do so, and it is also conventional to call it from the test using the `start` function.  Perhaps if you follow these conventions, you can more easily avoid errors of this type.